# Unlogged table in postgres in hot standby database

Tags: postgresql-9.1

we have a pair of posgresql 9.1 servers operating in streaming replication mode. In each of these server there are 2 databases.

One is a "live" database which has data that must be replicated as close to realtime as possible and one is a "cache" database that has data that is not important and can be regenerated or built up over a period of time.

The "cache" database uses unlogged tables for everything (since we don't care if they get truncated) and we effectively use it as a kind of in-memory database. It works exceptionally well since we have lots of read/writes to these tables. We seen dramatic performance increases on servers with high load and lots of memory using the unlogged tables.

The problem now comes in when we have to create another "cache" database on the slave side. We need this for our web application to work properly. Of source with the database being in read-only mode this is not possible...

Just wondering if anyone else has a similar issue or if there is a way to create an unlogged table on the slave server? Streaming replication seems to be "all or nothing" in postgres and you can't turn it on/off for a particular database.

Perhaps I'm using unlogged tables incorrectly, but so far haven't managed to find anything that works as well as they do.

Any pointers would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

> Streaming replication seems to be "all or nothing" in postgres and you can't turn it on/off for a particular database.

Unfortunately, this is correct. WAL replication is for an entire database cluster, and you're asking a database inside the cluster on the master to not be logged, so there's no way to make it appear on the slave.

The best solution I have found is to run a second daemon / cluster on the slave and create the unlogged cache database there. There's no real problem with running multiple daemons of postgres at the same time - you'll just need to make sure you specify a different socket / port for it to listen on.